# How to implement 'Reset ' in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a reset button that resets the quiz game at the end of the quiz.

I created a button and a function that should handle the event. but while the default values are re-initialized, the question doesn't render on the screen.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    Replay: false,
    counter: 0,
    questionId: 1,
    question: '',
    answerOptions: [],
    answer: '',
    answersCount: {
      Clever: 0,
      Just_average: 0,
      Very_dull: 0
    },
    result: ''
  };

  this.handleAnswerSelected = this.handleAnswerSelected.bind(this);
}

 componentWillMount() {
    const shuffledAnswerOptions = quizQuestions.map((question) => this.shuffleArray(question.answers));
    this.setState({
      question: quizQuestions[0].question,
      answerOptions: shuffledAnswerOptions[0]
    });
  }

 ...........................................................

// Even handler function
restart(event){

  this.setState ({
    counter: 0,
    questionId: 1,
    question: '',
      answerOptions: [],
      answer: '',
      answersCount: { 
        Clever: 0,
        Just_average: 0,
        Very_dull: 0,
      },
      result: ''
  })
}
```

code placed inside the render/return of App.js

```
  </div>
    {this.state.result ? this.renderResult() : this.renderQuiz()}
  </div>
```

................................

renderQuiz() {
    return (
      
    );
  }

renderResult() {
    return (
      
    );
  }

Comment: Could you show renderResult and renderQuiz method bodies?

Comment: try to put this.renderQuiz() in callback of setstate like this.setState ({ anything: anything }, () => this.renderQuiz())

Comment: try use componentDidMounth() instead of componentWillMount and check if state.result is empty

Comment: @MetehanSenol just added the renderResult and renderQuiz method bodies

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting the same state in constructor+componentWillMount  and in reset you can create a function like getNewState which can be reused at both places by removing componentWillMount.
This approach can be used if you have all data available at start.

If you are getting some data from api then you have to merge the api data with state in componentWillMount. But while resetting as data is already available you can use getNewState as it is.

something like below.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const state = this.getNewState();
    this.state = state; 

    this.handleAnswerSelected = this.handleAnswerSelected.bind(this);
}

function getNewState() {
    const shuffledAnswerOptions = quizQuestions.map((question) => this.shuffleArray(question.answers));
    return {
        Replay: false,
        counter: 0,
        questionId: 1,
        question: quizQuestions[0].question,
        answerOptions: shuffledAnswerOptions[0],
        answer: '',
        answersCount: {
            Clever: 0,
            Just_average: 0,
            Very_dull: 0
        },
        result: ''
    };
}

// Even handler function
restart(event){
    const state = this.getNewState();
    this.setState(state);
}
```